# How to find the position in original list ranked first by SortBy

Tags: function-construction, sorting

`SortBy` is a wonder and convenient way to sort a list using a list of functions with which ties can be broken.

```
input = {{x, 0}, {b, 1, 2}, {c, 2}};
SortBy[input, {Length, First}]
(* {{c, 2}, {x, 0}, {b, 1, 2}} *)
```

However, is there a fast function that will just tell me the position of the element of the `input` ranked first by `SortBy`?  In the case above, the answer I'm looking for is `3`.

I'm looking for a built-in that does this, or a fast function that can get the result for larger (size of ~1000) lists and lots of tie-breaking functions.

Comment: If WRI creates such system functions, it should be called `MaxBy` and `MinBy` or `FirstBy` and `LastBy`.

Comment: @JasonB. My v11.3 doesn't know of `OrderingBy` - where is it implemented?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't think those functions (I guess you mean `MaximalBy` etc.) implement the "tie-breaking" part of the question, which seems either unique to `SortBy`, or undocumented for other similar functions. Well, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @kirma:  I'm assuming that the yet-to-be-written function would indeed implement tie-breaking rules.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Ah! I missed that small "if" there.

Comment: @kirma, my mistake.

Comment: @JasonB. Waiting for it to appear on the language, though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility:

```
Ordering[Through @* {Length, First} /@ input, 1]
```

> {3}

Comment: Very interesting way to represent the tie-breaking concept using the "natural" sorting order of lists!

Comment: As a further note: I considered implementing a solution with `Fold`. Transforming input entries to lists which perform tie-breaking directly on sorting-related functions is million times better an approach.

Comment: Nice!  I found this solution too just before I checked on here; good to see agreement.